# Remove comma from java script array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to know how to remove comma from below list array elements, my code:

```
var lUserNames= [];
$.each(lUsers, function( index, value ) {
    lUserNames.push("<li>" + lUsers[index].name + "</li>");
    lUserNames.join("");
});
```

Output with above code:

```
. User1
,
. User2
,
. User3
```

I've tried several methods for joining, none of which worked.

Comment: How can i remove that comma? @Rayon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apply `Array#join` after `$.each` loop

```js
var lUserNames = [];
var lUsers = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$.each(lUsers, function() {
  lUserNames.push("<li>" + this + "</li>");
});
var op = lUserNames.join("");
console.log(op);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I did not assign it to another variable after using join, Its working now @Rayon