# Append A href Inside Div Using Ajax Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Please Help, im new to Ajax, Jquery
This is my Data:

```
MenuID   MenuName   SubMenuName
1        Menu1      SubMenu1
4        Menu4      SubMenu4
4        Menu4      SubMenu5
4        Menu4      SubMenu6
```

This is my Code :

```
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var card_menu = $('#id_card');
            var html = '';
            html = ''
                + '<div class="col-xl-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">'
                  + '<div class="card text-white bg-success o-hidden h-100">'
                    + '<div class="card-body">'
                      + '<div class="card-body-icon">'
                        + '<i class="' + data[i].csMenuCss + '"></i>'
                      + '</div>'
                      + '<div class="mr-5">' + data[i].csMenuName + '</div>'
                    + '</div>'
                        + '<a class="card-footer text-white clearfix small z-1" href="#">'
                          + '<span class="float-left"> ' + Show Here Sub Menu + ' </span>'
                          + '<span class="float-right">'
                            + '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
                          + '</span>'
                        + '</a>'
                  + '</div>'
                + '</div>';
            card_menu.append(html);
        }
    },
```

Ive search all over the net but i ddint get any answers, 
I want to show to the Div like this..
Thanks :)

```
Menu1
- Menu1

Menu4
- Menu4
- Menu5
- Menu6
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the answer..

```
                success: function (result) {
                    var card_menu = $('#id_card');
                    var html = '';
                    var html1 = [];
                    var html2 = '';
                    var html3 = '';
                    html = ''
                        + '<div class="col-xl-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">'
                          + '<div class="card text-white bg-success o-hidden">'
                            + '<div class="card-body">'
                              + '<div class="card-body-icon">'
                                + '<i class="' + '' + '"></i>'
                              + '</div>'
                              + '<div class="mr-5">' + result[0].csMenuName + '</div>'
                            + '</div>';
                    for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                        html1[j] = ''
                                    + '<a class="card-footer text-white clearfix small z-1" href="' + 'hris/' + result[j].csMenuUrl + '/' + result[j].csSubMenuUrl + '.aspx' +'">'
                                      + '<span class="float-left">' + result[j].csSubMenuName + '</span>'
                                      + '<span class="float-right">'
                                        + '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>'
                                      + '</span>'
                                    + '</a>';
                              **"it shows here"**
                    }
                    html2 = ''
                          + '</div>'
                        + '</div>';

                    html3 = html + html1 + html2;
                    card_menu.append(html3);
                }
```

Comment: just found the answer again... just want to share with you guys .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38184211/remove-comma-from-java-script-array